# Java EE, Web Service Client, Java

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a web service and built a client. I wrote a xhtml page that sends a name and phone number to the web service. If I use the Bean to send the strings using setters and getters the web service returns null values to the client. If I instead enter direct string into the function I get the correct strings back from the web service.

```
public void submit()
{ PhoneBookProxy.addEntries(name, phoneNum);}
```

This doesn't work.

```
public void submit()
{ PhoneBookProxy.addEntries("Jane Doe", "555 555-5555"); }
```

This does work.

This is for homework. Thanks for all the help.

I am using Netbeans with JDK 1.7

```
@ManagedBean
@NoneScoped
public class phoneBookClient {

private String firName, lasName, thphoneNum;
private PhoneBook PhoneBookProxy;

public phoneBookClient()
{
    PhoneBook_Service service = new PhoneBook_Service();
     PhoneBookProxy = service.getPhoneBookPort();
}

public void setFirstName(String fName)
{
    firName = fName;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firName;
}

  public void setLastName(String lName)
{
    lasName = lName;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lasName;
}

public void setPhoneNum(String phoneNum)
{
    thphoneNum = phoneNum;
}

public String getPhoneNum()
{
    return thphoneNum;
}

public void submit()
{
    PhoneBookProxy.addEntry(getLastName(), getFirstName(), getPhoneNum());
}

public List<Object> getEntries()
{
    return PhoneBookProxy.getEntries();
}
```

}

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
    <title>Phone Book Client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please fill in all fields and click Submit</h1>
    <h:form>
        <h2>Please Enter your First Name</h2>
            <h:inputText id="fnameInputText" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Please enter your First name"
                value="#{phoneBookClient.firstName}"
                validatorMessage="Name must be fewer than 30 characters">
                <f:validateLength maximum="30" />
          </h:inputText>
        <h:message for="fnameInputText" />
        <br />
        <h2>Please Enter your Last Name</h2>
        <h:inputText id="lnameInputText" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Please enter your Last name"
                value="#{phoneBookClient.lastName}"
                validatorMessage="Name must be fewer than 30 characters">
                <f:validateLength maximum="30" />
          </h:inputText>
        <h:message for="lnameInputText" />
        <br />
        <h2>Please enter your phone number in format: (xxx) xxx-xxxx</h2>
        <h:inputText id="phoneInputText" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Please enter a valid phone number"
                value="#{phoneBookClient.phoneNum}"
                validatorMessage="Invalid phone number format">
                <f:validateRegex pattern=
                   "((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{phoneBookClient.submit()}"/>
        </h:form>
    <ui:repeat var="list" value="#{phoneBookClient.entries}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{list}" />
        <br />
    </ui:repeat>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the values from `name` and `phoneNum` in `submit()` method?

Comment: Sounds like the `name` and `phoneNum` variables are null. Can you post the code that sets those values?

Comment: Sounds like the setters either don't work or aren't being called.

Comment: please provide more code, which frameworks you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not about web services, it is about setting variables in jsf beans.

Why are you using `@NoneScoped` in your managed bean definition? This does not suit your case.

You may use `@ViewScoped` if you are using jsf 2+ . You may read [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) about this concept.

As a side note, this is a bad coding practice.

```
 public String getFirstName()
 {
    return firName;
 }
```

Define your variable as FirstName not firName, or if it is firName write your methods like getFirName

Comment: Using @ViewScoped worked. Thanks. I know that using a different string like that is bad practice. That came about as me trying to fix the problem. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It would be good to refer to [Communication in JSF 2](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) to provide an even better answer :)

Comment: Edited the answer, that article is definitely a must read.

Comment: @SerkanArıkuşu I have it as favorite, just too lazy to post it.